# How can extract this information from web whatsapp; using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp, information-extraction

[Numbers from a group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7yHp.png)

[Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9PvH.png)

Hello to everyone i hope yall good.
i want to extract these numbers from webwhatsapp using selenium

This is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import os

dir_path = os.getcwd()
profile = os.path.join(dir_path, "profile", "wpp")
s=Service('chromedriver.exe')
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
op.add_argument(
    r"user-data-dir={}".format(profile))


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=op)

url='https://web.whatsapp.com'
driver.get(url)

numbers=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "zzgSd _3e6xi").text
print(numbers)
```

But this dosnt work.
Please help me!!

Comment: That's actually class names "zzgSd _3e6xi" which is  grabbed by css selector with a . in front of the class names so ".zzgSd._3e6xi". However they seem dynamic so they most likely will change. It would be better to find a more unique xpath.

Comment: they dont change to be honest. but dosent grab all the numbers nither.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the element in inspect browser and copy selector path[image: CSS_Selector]

And in selenium use `numbers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#paste the path').text`